# How to show the combinations of a column in SQL along with the aggregated results?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The question is on SQL:
**Create a summary table to show how many customers use different GO-JEK services in a daily
basis, along with the combination of services used (Please see below screenshot for more
details).**

Several conditions for this task:

- Take only order_status = “Completed”
- No repetition on details of order_type

  - You can combine it in any order but every combination is only allowed once. E.g.
    same combinations like RIDE, CAR, SEND and CAR, RIDE, SEND are
    unacceptable
- Group each order_payment and its combination

  - I.e. aggregations by CASH, GOPAY, CASH&GOPAY (ALL)
- Use date in UTC timezone

**Dataset sample: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LIUm9I9JdG4It_-ImAFQh-TSdNrd_pAN/view?usp=sharing)**

[image]

I'm not sure on getting the `order_type` combinations. Please suggest.

Comment: Could you clarify what your requirements are? Do you want the logic for whole table creation or only for finding different order_type combinations?

Comment: I'd like to know the query /logic for the result table.